# How to pivot table with T-SQL?

Tags: t-sql, pivot

How to convert table from this format:

```
Id | Data           |Section
------------------------------------------
1  |1AAA            |AAA
------------------------------------------
1  |1BBB            |BBB
------------------------------------------
1  |1CCC            |CCC
------------------------------------------
2  |2AAA            |AAA
------------------------------------------
2  |2BBB            |BBB
------------------------------------------
2  |2CCC            |CCC
------------------------------------------
3  |3AAA            |AAA
------------------------------------------
3  |3CCC            |CCC
------------------------------------------
```

To this format with T-sql ?

```
Id |Column_AAA|Column_BBB|Colunm_CCC|
-------------------------------------
1  |1AAA      |1BBB      |1CCC      |   
-------------------------------------
2  |2AAA      |2BBB      |2CCC      |       
-------------------------------------
3  |3AAA      |.....     |3CCC      |
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

this should give you the results you want.

```
CREATE TABLE #temp
(
    id int,
    data varchar(50),
    section varchar(50)
)
insert into #temp values(1, '1AAA', 'AAA')
insert into #temp values(1, '1BBB', 'BBB')
insert into #temp values(1, '1CCC', 'CCC')
insert into #temp values(2, '2AAA', 'AAA')
insert into #temp values(2, '2BBB', 'BBB')
insert into #temp values(2, '2CCC', 'CCC')
insert into #temp values(3, '3AAA', 'AAA')
insert into #temp values(3, '3BBB', 'BBB')
insert into #temp values(3, '3CCC', 'CCC')

select id, [AAA] as Column_AAA, [BBB] as Column_BBB, [CCC] as Column_CCC
from 
(
    select id, data, section
    from #temp
) x
PIVOT
(
    max(data)
    FOR section IN([AAA], [BBB], [CCC])
) as p

drop table #temp
```

Results:

```
id  column_AAA column_BBB   column_CCC
1   1AAA        1BBB        1CCC
2   2AAA        2BBB        2CCC
3   3AAA        3BBB        3CCC
```