# PIVOT table for account data with columns for each month

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2005, pivot

The table I am looking in has the following columns:

```
department_number, amount, date_created.
```

I'm trying to create a table that shows the total amount for each department for each month in 2013, so it would look like this:

```
Department_number, Jan Amount, Feb Amount, March Amt, etc....
```

Is this a case for pivot tables, or should I just run a different query for each month and join them?

Comment: Must it be done in sql, tools like excle can 'link' to the data and pivot this for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your case is certainly a candidate for using PIVOT table syntax. The below is a simple query which does pivot.

```
SELECT Department_number
,[January]
,[February]
,[March]
FROM (
SELECT Department_number, Amount, datename(date_created) AS month_created from <Your_Table>
) AS SOURCETABLE
PIVOT(SUM([Amount]) FOR month_created IN ([January],[February],[March])) AS PIVOTTABLE
```

This query assumes you have date_created column containing values Jan,Feb,March in your table. You may add more months if you need.

More on the subject - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: What if the date_created is a datetime data type? can I use month(date_created) ?

Comment: Thank you very much, I was able to get this to work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display this in SSRS report then go for Row and Column grouping and aggregate the amount otherwise you can use Pivot Table with TSQL : [How to pivot table with T-SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9830960/how-to-pivot-table-with-t-sql)

Comment: this is more of a comment then an answer.